# In a ScrollView, a RelativeLayout child height is 0

Tags: android, android-layout

I should see a left blue panel and a green right panel in a scroll area. But the height of the left panel is 0. Do you know how to fix it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFF0000" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/right_panel"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="20000dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="#FF00FF00" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/left_panel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/right_panel"
            android:background="#FF0000FF" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Replace your RelativeLayout with This one.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFF0000" >


    <View
        android:id="@+id/right_panel"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#FF00FF00" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/left_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right_panel"
        android:background="#FF0000FF" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try to change RelativeLayout to LinearLayout(Horizontal).

Comment: I found the solution I have to align bottom and top of the left panel to the right panel.

   
            <View
                android:id="@+id/left_panel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/right_panel"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/right_panel"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/right_panel"
                android:background="#FF0000FF" />